# How to limit resource usage of a job in YARN

Tags: hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I remember some recent version of YARN has a configuration parameter which controls the amount of memory (or cores) a job can use. I tried to find it from the Web but I couldn't yet. If you know the parameter, please let me know.

I know one way to go about this is to use some kind of scheduler but for now I need a job level control so that the job doesn't abuse the entire system.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can control maximum and minimum resource which are allocated to each containers.

- `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb`: Minimum memory allocation for each container
- `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb`: Maximum memory allocation for each container
- `yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores`: Minimum core allocation for each container
- `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-vcores`: Maximum core allocation for each container

If you want to avoid abuse of user jobs, `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-*` can be solution because RM refuses the request which requires above these restriction by throwing `InvalidResourceRequestException`.

ref: [yarn-default.xml](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml)